# Upgrade Apache Superset 0.19.0 to the latest (1.3.2?)

Tags: apache-superset

We want to upgrade our old superset installation (0.19.0) to the latest version (1.3.2 or 1.4.0), and are just wondering whether there is anything we need to do to migrate the existing dashboards?

All meta data sits in AWS RDS database. Do we need to make any change in the DB, or just simply connect to it from the new Superset version?

Answer (score 0):

Export all the dashboards, connect the to the  database from the new supersert version and import the dashboards to the new environment

Comment: Hey @Lenin, Thanks for the help! I just tried that but the old superset export dashboard in pkl format, while the new one use JSON. I may try to open the pkl to see whats there and whether it is possible to save as JSON, but just not sure whether it is worthy the effort, or maybe we would be better to recreate the dashboard from scratch.